# What programming language should a physics major know?

Tags: physics, code, soft-skills

Know how of what programming language will come in handy during a physics major's research ?

Comment: Some physicists I know make a lot of use of Scilab.

Comment: To make this on topic, change "academics" to "research" and "major" to "research student"

Comment: I think _everyone_ should know python,  but that doesn't really answer your question. What do you do in physics?

Comment: Would highschool level python do any good ? @Fábio Dias

Comment: @theenigma017 any good physics undergraduate degree will teach you the Python you need to know.

Comment: To make this question on-topic, ask which programming languages are most frequently used in physics research, and specifically if there exist any polls or surveys on the topic.

Comment: These on topic off topic claims ruin user experience at stack exchange , This wasnt' some innapropriate/irrelevent question you know , not far off either and  you guys are way too strict , stack exchange is turning into a war for reputation and authority ! @henning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ability to write computer programs is very important for a physicist because it helps you be more productive.  However, knowledge of a particular language is not very useful.  The reason is that different situations call for different languages.  Usually, the most important thing about the situation is the preferences of the people you are working with.

What you need to know are

- Basic computer science concepts, such as data structures and
  algorithms
- How to write maintainable code
- How to read documentation, which is extremely important, since you will constantly be learning to deal with specialized interfaces.

Learning any major multi-paradigm programming language will achieve this goal.  For example, C++, Java, R, Python, Perl, Mathematica, or Matlab.  Just expect to switch later.  Keep in mind languages are interoperable these days.

My final advice would be:

1. Avoid learning the way people did it decades ago, as a lot has changed.
2. Your fellow physicists may be good at physics, but they are often bad programmers.  Try to be at least mediocre.
3. If you are an academic you will mostly write LaTeX, which will be easy once you know how to program.

Comment: To what extent must C++ be known to be of use in physics ?

Comment: @theenigma017 Enough to be able to read the documentation on a C++ library, so you can use the library with the language of your choice.  Definitely enough to understand the data structures.  It may vary by situation.

Comment: Don't forget Fortran!

Comment: @astronat I did not forget; FORTRAN, while widely used, is about 30 years older and not so suitable for pedagogy.  Yes, I am aware it has been updated.